# Android SQL database path in DDMS

Tags: android, sql, database, ddms

I have project which goes like this in the DDMS path

packagename->FolderA->FolderB->DatabaseFile.db

now there are many tables in this db file.I want to insert to a MyTable table.
So can anyone help me form the correct uri?

content://packagename/   then?

Comment: You want to insert data in MyTable table ?

Comment: yes I just want to know the correct Uri to MyTable

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your whole folder structure resides in removable sd card

```
if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
{
File directory=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File myFolder=new File(directory+"/FolderA/FolderB/DatabaseFile.db");
 }
```

Comment: No,it resides on device's internal storage.

Comment: Then try this` File directory=Environment.getDataDirectory(); File mydir=new File(dicrectory+"/data/FolderA/FolderB/DatabaseFile.db") `

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void copyDataBase(Context mActivity) throws IOException {
```

- **InputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(new File("/data/data/"
                  + mActivity.getPackageName() + "/databases/"
                  + "xxxx.sqlite"));**

  ```
      File files = new File("/sdcard/files/");
      files.mkdirs();
      String outFileName = "/sdcard/files/xxxx.sqlite";
      OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      int bufferLength;
      while ((bufferLength = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
          myOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
      }
      myOutput.flush();
      myOutput.close();
      myInput.close();
  }
  ```

above function copy from ur data->data database to sdcard.

***InputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(new File("/data/data/"
                    + mActivity.getPackageName() + "/databases/"
                    + "xxxx.sqlite"));****

this line is used to get database path.

I hope its helpful to you.

Comment: No,it resides on device's internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

You just create the database like this

```
SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("MYDB",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
```

To insert into the table

```
db.execSQL("create table if not exists mytable (fname varchar,lname varchar);");
db.execSQL("insert into mytable values('my first name','my last name')";);
```

To see the database goto

**`DDMS->data->data->com.example.package->databases`**

Try it..